# Spring Boot Java Config - split web (controllers, etc), and services

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

In my old XML config projects, I could do the following in my configurations

`mvc-context.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

`service-context.xml`

```
<context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" >
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

in my tests, I could then do the following

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy(value = {
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { MockServices.class }),
    @ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:/META-INF/spring/mvc-servlet-context.xml" }),
})
public class FooControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }
}
```

and I could then run tests against the my MVC configuration, without loading my services and JPA respositories, and instead have my mocks `@Autowired` into my controllers.

However, Spring Boot applications have the following in the main context configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
}
```

This `@ComponentScan` obviously finds all `@Controller`, `@Service`, etc

if I now tried to test my MVC context, I would load the unwanted services and repositories.

What I attempted to do was create 2 new configurations

`Mvc.java`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo" }, useDefaultFilters = false, includeFilters = {@Filter(value = org.springframework.stereotype.Controller.class)} )
@Order(2)
public class Mvc {
}
```

`Services.java`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo" }, useDefaultFilters = false, excludeFilters = {@Filter(value = org.springframework.stereotype.Controller.class)} )
@Order(1)
public class Services {
}
```

This however does not work, when I try start my app, I will get `@Autowire` errors `No qualifying bean of type`

Am I going about this the wrong way?

How do I make it so that I can run tests on my MVC context, without the time penalty of loading JPA EntityManagers, Spring Data Repositories, etc?

Comment: can you please put in the stack error so that we can troubleshoot

Comment: You are copy-pasting to much. Remove the `useDefaultFilters` attribute from the `Services` class. Also do you really need the context if all you want to do is test a controller, just create an instance yourself and mock the services needed in your unit test and/or use Spring Test MockMVC to test your controllers.

Comment: Not sure what copy-paste has to do with anything, surely without the `useDefaultFilters` and `excludeFilters` the controllers will be loaded twice? using `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` is semi ok, except that it will not include all the other things used by MVC, eg `ControllerAdvice`, `ExceptionResolvers`, `ConversionServices`, etc. That is why I want to use `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup`. I have updated the above code to show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538710/spring-boot-java-config-split-web-controllers-etc-and-services/26545249#comment41708608_26538710) gave in the comments is correct but may be you didn't get the hint.
when you say:
`useDefaultFilters = false` and `excludeFilters = {@Filter(value = org.springframework.stereotype.Controller.class)}`
nothing will be found because `useDefaultFilters = false` will prevent spring from looking for stereotype annotations like `@Controller, @Service ...`

[Link to Spring API doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#useDefaultFilters--)

Comment: After reading the source for `ComponentScanAnnotationParser` this indeed does now make sense. I am wondering how my xml configuration actually even works, because it also includes `useDefaultFilter=false` with an `excludeFilters`